# Flowplayer event when buffering ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer, buffering, http-live-streaming

I'm using flowplayer to play an MP4 video on a website from a NGinx server with H264 streaming plugin, and the pseudostreaming plugin for Flowplayer. Everything works fine.

I implemented several javascript functions for deep linking into the video, with the $f().Seek() method, which also works fine.

Here is my problem : when the user seeks to a particular place in the video, I need to disable some elements on the page, to prevent him or her from clicking more times, jamming all the sync. Then, I want to re-enable the same elements when the video starts playing again.

This code disables the elements and is placed in the click event of some buttons. Straightforward :
`$('.cur-left, .cur-right, .book-temps').hide('fast');`

This code enables them :
`$('.cur-left, .cur-right, .book-temps').show('fast');`

I can't find where to place my "re-enabling" code, as no event seems to happen when the video restarts playing after buffering after a seek.

Any advice on an unknown event matching or a trick to fit it some other way would be unvaluable.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Found a workaround by seeking a few seconds before the cuepoint and toggle the hidden elements on cuepoints, but the system is unreliable, so the question remains more open than ever. Please feel free to share any clue, even small ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need handle onBufferFull event:

```
<!-- player container  -->
<a href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv" id="player"
    style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px"> 

    <!-- .. with a splash image -->
    <img src="http://static.flowplayer.org/img/home/flow_eye.jpg" alt="Search engine friendly content" /> 
</a>
<div id="info">
</div>
```

and script:

```
$(function(){
    var info = document.getElementById("info");

    flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {

        // this will enable pseudostreaming support 
        plugins: { 
            pseudo: { url: 'flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.7.swf' } 
        },

        // listen to following clip events 
        clip: {        
            // make this clip use pseudostreaming plugin with "provider" property
            provider: 'pseudo',                

            // all videos under this baseUrl support pseudostreaming on the server side        
            url: 'http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/Extremists.flv'            
        },

        onBufferFull: function() {
           info.innerHTML += "buffer full<br/>";
        }                        

    });    
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tJCLG/)

Comment: Excellent ! I didn't dare to try this one, as I thought it would only fire after the video started replaying, but I was wrong : it happens exactly at the useful time. Thanks a lot. For the record, here's the JQuery binding at runtime :          $f().onBufferFull(function() {
              $('.cur-left, .cur-right, .book-temps').show('fast');
           }
          );